# Java calculation in Atomic

Tags: java, parallel-processing, atomicinteger

I have a small question about Java `AtomicInteger`.
I know that I can realise thread-safe counters. But I couldn't find anything about complex calculations with `AtomicInteger`.

For example I have this calculation (i and j are object-vars, "this"):

```
public void test(int x) {
    i = i + ( j * 3 ) + x
}
```

Is it possible to make this method thread-safe only with `AtomicInteger`?

Is this valid?

```
public void test(int x) {
    do {
        int tempi = i.get();
        int tempj = j.get();
        int calc = tempi + ( tempj * 3 ) + x;
    } while (i.compareAndSet(tempi, calc));
}
```

I think not because a thread could change j while the calculation.
To avoid this I have to control if j is changed while the calculation. But I don't find a "just compare" function in `AtomicInteger`.

Pseudocode:

```
public void test(int x) {
    do {
        int tempi = i.get();
        int tempj = j.get();
        int calc = tempi + ( tempj * 3 ) + x;
    } while (i.compareAndSet(tempi, calc) && j.compare(tempj) /* changed */);
}
```

Can anybody help me to clarification?

Comment: No. Neither are valid as you say. The first because `j` may have changed and the second because you write anyway, then check `j`; if this check fails then you've already written. The only way to do this correctly would be to have some sort of external lock. You could try and pack two `int` into an `AtomicLong`, that way allowing you to have a single value again.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your calculations operate on multiple `AtomicXXX` objects (`i`, `j`) they are not thread-safe. `AtomicXXX` semantics are implemented with [Compare-and-Swap (CAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) instructions that do not support more than one placeholder at a time. You need an external monitor lock to make it thread-safe.